# Parameter not changing in OleDbCommand

Tags: c#, asp.net, oledb

This is a simple search page (search.aspx?title=Hello) and I want to query the db for like matches. According to the microsoft docs (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbparameter.aspx see: Remarks) this is the correct way to do it, but the parameter (?) never gets set to the value of the query string.

```
        string sqlcmd = "SELECT * FROM TableName WHERE Title LIKE ?";

        OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand(sqlcmd, sqlcon);

        OleDbParameter p1 = new OleDbParameter("@p1", OleDbType.WChar);
        p1.Value =  Request.QueryString["title"];         

        OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter(command);
        da.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add(p1);

        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        da.Fill(dt);
```

The parameter never changes to what the query string was, it just executes the query

```
        SELECT * FROM Table WHERE Title LIKE ?
```

Comment: But the query works or not?

Comment: it executes as is, SELECT * FROM Table WHERE Title LIKE ?

Comment: Use SELECT * FROM Table WHERE Title LIKE '_' and see if it works for a single character

Comment: @Shriroop Exactly the same thing, it just executes as is

Comment: What kind of database are you using? The datatable is empty after the Fill call?

Comment: @user2892146, are you sure you are getting something in `Request.QueryString["title"]`, because if it is `null` probably an empty string is send to the query

Comment: Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0 and yes the datatable is empty

Comment: @Habib yes I made sure that works fine

Comment: Is your table really named 'Table'?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It's good to see that you've posted your code, but it's generally a good idea to also explain your problem in plain English: What you're trying to do, what you expect your code to do, and what it's actually doing. You've got the last part done well enough, though.

Answer (score 1):

Could you try the following:

```
"SELECT * FROM Table WHERE Title LIKE @p1"
```

I think that is the convention when using parameters in ADO.Net command text.

Comment: If I do something like SELECT * FROM TableName WHERE Title=@p1 it works, but it doesn't work with a LIKE.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution, you need to have single quotes around the question mark for the SQL to work. Complete solution:

sqlcon.Open();

```
        string sqlcmd = "SELECT * FROM TableName WHERE Title LIKE '%?%'";

        OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand(sqlcmd, sqlcon);     

        command.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("p1", Request.QueryString["Title"]));

        OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter(command);

        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        da.Fill(dt);
```